# R- mutate on pattern matching columns and create new var

Tags: r, dplyr

My dataset is like this

```
  id start_year subj1_year subj2_year
1  1 2010       2001       2003
2  2 2012       2002       2004
3  3 2015       2003       2005
4  4 2021       2004       2006
```

I want to create a new column for each `"Subj"`, with the difference between each `subject_year` and the `start_year` column (duration):

```
 id start_year subj1_year subj2_year subj1_duration subj2_duration
1  1 2010       2001       2003              9              7
2  2 2012       2002       2004             10              8
3  3 2015       2003       2005             12             10
4  4 2021       2004       2006             17             15
```

What could be a solution using `dplyr`?
Thank you!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use `across` to avoid repeating the code -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with('subj'), 
          ~start_year - ., .names = '{sub("year", "duration", .col)}'))

#  id start_year subj1_year subj2_year subj1_duration subj2_duration
#1  1       2010       2001       2003              9              7
#2  2       2012       2002       2004             10              8
#3  3       2015       2003       2005             12             10
#4  4       2021       2004       2006             17             15
```

`.names` parameters is used to assign the names to new columns, changing "year" to "duration".

Answer (score 1):

We could do this with `base R`

```
nm1 <- grep("subj", names(df), value = TRUE)
df[sub("year", "duration", nm1)] <- df$start_year - df[nm1]
```

-ouptut

```
> df
  id start_year subj1_year subj2_year subj1_duration subj2_duration
1  1       2010       2001       2003              9              7
2  2       2012       2002       2004             10              8
3  3       2015       2003       2005             12             10
4  4       2021       2004       2006             17             15
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:4, start_year = c(2010L, 2012L, 2015L, 
2021L), subj1_year = 2001:2004, subj2_year = 2003:2006), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"))
```